# Der Unterschied zwischen "In Anspruch nehmen", "verwenden" und "benutzen"

Tags: difference, verb, expression

> Ich werde morgen meinen Wagen für die Arbeit in Anspruch nehmen.
>
> Ich werde morgen meinen Wagen für die Arbeit verwenden.
>
> Ich werde morgen meinen Wagen für die Arbeit benutzen.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den drei Verben und sind sie untereinander austauschbar?

Comment: Den Wagen für die Arbeit verwenden/benutzen klingt komisch. Ich denke, du willst sagen "Ich fahre morgen mit meinem Wagen zur Arbeit" oder "Ich werde morgen für meine Fahrt zur Arbeit meinen Wagen nehmen", aber der  Satz oben klingt, als bräuchtest du den Wagen um deine eigentliche Arbeit auszuführen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich sehe den wesentlichen Unterschied darin, dass *benutzen* nur bei Gegenständen wirklich trifft, während *in Anspruch nehmen* sich vorwiegend auf Dienstleistungen bezieht.

Wenn ein Mädchen nach einer tränenreichen Trennung feststellt: "Er hat mich nur benutzt", bringt sie damit gerade zum Ausdruck, dass sie sich wie ein Gegenstand und nicht wie eine Person behandelt fühlt.

Die Dienste eines Steuerberaters, Maklers (oder Freundes beim Umzug) in Anspruch nehmen heißt nicht, dass man einen Rechtsanspruch darauf hat, man zahlt nur hinterher dafür (bzw. lädt ihn zum Essen ein).

Bei Versicherungen oder einem Dispo- oder Überziehungskredit spricht man von "in Anspruch nehmen", weil es eine Dienstleistung ist; hier wird dann aber die Grenze zur juristischen Bedeutung überschritten (siehe die jeweiligen Vertrags- bzw. Geschäftsbedingungen), in diese Kategorie gehört auch der "Urlaubsanspruch".

Es gibt schließlich noch die stehende Wendung *Ich nehme für mich in Anspruch …*, die nichts mit Obigem zu tun hat, sondern einfach *Ich behaupte von mir …* bedeutet.

Answer (score 6):

Bei Deinen drei Verben sind *verwenden* und *benutzen* in diesem Kontext synonym, *in Anspruch nehmen* unterscheidet sich deutlich.

Um etwas in Anspruch zu nehmen, muss ein *Anspruch* vorliegen oder geschaffen werden, also im weitesten Sinne ein Recht, das man ausübt.  Nimmt man einen Gegenstand in Anspruch, so fordert man sein Recht ein, ihn zu benutzen. *Meistens*, aber nicht zwingend, kommt der Begriff in juristischen oder ähnlich formalen Kontexten vor. Aber:
Auch Aufgaben (oder Kinder!) können *Zeit in Anspruch nehmen* – noch immer recht formal formuliert, aber ohne implizit juristischen Hintergrund, lediglich in der Bedeutung *es braucht Zeit, um XY zu tun*.

---

Nicht Teil der Frage, aber dennoch:
Keins der drei Beispiele klingt idiomatisch. Ich verstehe die Sätze so, dass Du planst, morgen mit dem Auto ins Büro oder zum Kunden zu fahren, wohingegen Du das sonst nicht immer tust. (Bitte korrigieren, falls ich falsch liege!)

*In Anspruch nehmen* würde implizieren, dass Du gegenüber z.B. einem Mitbesitzer Dein Recht geltend machst, den Wagen zu bestimmten Zeiten zu benutzen.
Für die Arbeit *verwenden* macht nur Sinn, wenn das Fahrzeug nicht als Transportmittel, sondern zur Ausübung der Arbeit dient – als Requisit für einen Fotografen, z.B. oder als Anschauungsmaterial im Unterricht; Ähnliches gilt für *benutzen*.

Eine bessere Formulierung könnte sein:

> Ich werde morgen mit dem Wagen zur Arbeit *fahren*.  -> Art der Fortbewegung
>   Ich werde morgen den Wagen (mit (zur Arbeit)) *nehmen*. -> Fahrzeug nicht zuhause / verfügbar für andere.

Answer (score 3):

Während *verwenden* und *benutzen* weitgehend synonym sind, unterscheidet sich die Bedeutung von *in Anspruch nehmen* doch erheblich.

Wenn jemand etwas in Anspruch nimmt, dann macht er von seinem Recht gebrauch, darüber zu verfügen (oder er maßt sich das Recht an, über etwas zu verfügen). Man wird diese Formulierung kaum verwenden, wenn die Nutzungsrechte an dem Gegenstand klar sind. In dem in der Frage verwendeten Beispiel deutet "meinen Wagen" darauf hin, dass der Sprecher Eigentümer des Fahrzeugs ist. Sofern er nicht anderen Personen, mit denen er auf einer derart förmlichen Ebene kommuniziert, bedingte Nutzungsrechte eingeräumt hat, wäre eine derartige Formulierung daher überraschend.